# How to dynamically enable/disable a button based on a form field selection?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Lets say I have a switch as shown below,

```
var switchKeyValue = CardService.newKeyValue()
    .setTopLabel("Switch key value widget label")
    .setContent("This is a key value widget with a switch on the right")
    .setSwitch(CardService.newSwitch()
        .setFieldName("form_input_switch_key")
        .setValue("form_input_switch_value")
        .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
            .setFunctionName("handleSwitchChange")));
```

And a button as shown below,

```
var textButton = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText("Open Link")
    .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
        .setUrl("https://www.google.com"))
```

I noticed, that the `Button` has a method [`setDisabled(disabled)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-button?authuser=0#setdisableddisabled). Can this be leveraged to disable/enable the button based on the switch selection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, see the following example:

We need to have a function that holds and returns the card:

```js
function createCard(val) {

  var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('toggleIt').setParameters({val: val.toString()});

  var textButton = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText("Open Link")
    .setDisabled(val)
    .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
        .setUrl("https://www.google.com"));

  var textButton2 = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText('Click me!')
    .setOnClickAction(action);


  var section = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('Disabled/Enabled').addWidget(textButton);
  var section2= CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('Switcher').addWidget(textButton2);


  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader()
    .setTitle('My toggle button'))
    .addSection(section)
    .addSection(section2)
    .build();

  return card;
}
```

As you see we pass a parameter to this function: `val`.

This parameter holds the state of the button, and anytime you click on the button2 it calls an action: `toggleIt`

`toggleIt` function will invert the state of the `val` value and update the card with [updateCard](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/navigation?authuser=0#updatecardcard)

Here you have it:

```js
function toggleIt(e) {
  var boolVal = e.parameters.val == 'true' ? true : false;
  var val = !boolVal;
  return CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(createCard(val));
}
```

You can easily adapt this to your code ;)

Comment: Is it not possible to achieve it without creating a new card?

Comment: It is possible and this is what the above example is doing: there is only one card and the toggle function updates it, it’s not creating a new one. Look at the updateCard link I’ve provided on the post ;) remember to mark it as solved if it is.